# PyInstalled my app and now Windows Defender thinks its a trojan? wth

Tags: python, build, pyinstaller, malware, false-positive

Aright so just recently I've created an app called Wmapper that allows users to keymap throughout windows. It has 2 directorys that have exe files in thema and those work perfectly and are not detected but then I created a hub application that allows you to launch those 2 exe and import json's to those folders. This all was done in python btw.

The libraries I used for my app were:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import subprocess
import sv_ttk
import shutil
import os
import webbrowser
import pywinstyles
```

I'm not sure whether some of the libraries are infected or not because It is my first time using a few of them like `sv_ttk` and `pywinstyles` although from what others have said they are not infected.

I know It's pretty common for this to happen when pyinstalling but this is the first time its happening to me. The trojan windows detected was :

```
trojan wacatac.b!ml
```

Here are some important parts of the code that maybe yall can take a look at?

Import JSON function:

```
def import_keymap_config():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("JSON files", "*.json")])
    if file_path:
        # Move the JSON file to the keymapdefault folder
        shutil.move(file_path, "keymapdefault/")
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        # Show a popup message
        popup_msg = f"Successfully imported the keymap configuration: {file_name}"
        popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
        popup.geometry("700x100")
        popup.title("Import Success")
        label = ttk.Label(popup, text=popup_msg)
        label.pack(pady=20)
        ok_button = ttk.Button(popup, text="OK", command=popup.destroy)
        ok_button.pack()

def import_swiping_keymap_config():
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("JSON files", "*.json")])
    if file_path:
        # Move the JSON file to the keymapdefault folder
        shutil.move(file_path, "keymapswipe/")
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        # Show a popup message
        popup_msg = f"Successfully imported the keymap configuration: {file_name}"
        popup = tk.Toplevel(root)
        popup.geometry("700x100")
        popup.title("Import Success")
        label = ttk.Label(popup, text=popup_msg)
        label.pack(pady=20)
        ok_button = ttk.Button(popup, text="OK", command=popup.destroy)
        ok_button.pack()
```

Open web browser links:

```
def open_github():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://github.com/FlippantDev/Wmapper")

def open_youtube():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCE-ixwTDDLOqRPz3InkWPYw")

def open_discord():
    webbrowser.open_new("https://discord.gg/[discord]")

button1 = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Github ", command=open_github, takefocus=0) 
button1.pack(fill="x", padx=10, pady=5)

button2 = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Youtube ", command=open_youtube, takefocus=0)
button2.pack(fill="x", padx=10, pady=5)

button2 = ttk.Button(button_frame, text="Discord ", command=open_discord, style="Accent.TButton", takefocus=0)
button2.pack(fill="x", padx=10, pady=5)

version_label = tk.Label(sidebar_frame, text="Wmapper v1.0.2", font=("Helvetica", 13), bg="#171717", fg="white")
version_label.pack(side="bottom", pady=(0, 20))
```

Settings tab:

```
    elif page_name == "Settings":
        # Setting up a frame to align widgets from left to right
        settings_frame = tk.Frame(page, bg="#1c1c1c")
        settings_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10, fill="both", expand=True)

        # Button to import keymap config for default keymap
        import_button = ttk.Button(settings_frame, text="Import Keymap Config for Default Keymap", command=import_keymap_config, style="Accent.TButton", takefocus=0)
        import_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        
        import_button2 = ttk.Button(settings_frame, text="Import Keymap Config for Swiping Keymap", command=import_swiping_keymap_config, style="Accent.TButton", takefocus=0)
        import_button2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        # Function to toggle glossy theme
        def toggle_glossy_theme():
                pywinstyles.apply_style(root, "acrylic")
        def toggleOFF_glossy_theme():
                pywinstyles.apply_style(root, "normal")

        # Create a section for appearance
        appearance_label = ttk.Label(settings_frame, text="Appearance Settings:", style="Accent.TLabel")
        appearance_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="w")

        # Button to toggle on glossy theme
        glossy_button = ttk.Button(settings_frame, text="Toggle On Glossy Theme (experimental)", command=toggle_glossy_theme, takefocus=0)
        glossy_button.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)

        # Button to toggle off glossy theme
        glossyOFF_button = ttk.Button(settings_frame, text="Toggle Off Glossy Theme (experimental)", command=toggleOFF_glossy_theme, takefocus=0)
        glossyOFF_button.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
```

oh and the feature to actualyl launch the executables:

```
# Function to launch the swiping keymap executable
def launch_swipe_executable():
    subprocess.Popen(["keymapswipe/main.exe"])

# Function to launch the default keymap executable
def launch_default_executable():
    subprocess.Popen(["keymapdefault/main.exe"])
```

Aright so the first thing I tried was to remove a library called TKHTMLVIEW and I removed that already and in the above code its not there + I wanted to removed it anyway.

The issue still persists.

I also tried to remove `sv_ttk` and `pywinstyles` but the issue was still there
I literally also removed the option to turn on glossy and unglossy themes but the issue was not going.

I tried to remove the import JSON function but guess what, the issue still persisted?

I took the steps that I needed to before coming here and now I'm here and idk what to do

Comment: Submit your exe for a malware check here: [Microsoft File Submission](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission), my program was also flagged as a virus but after sometime of form submission it got removed

Comment: I don't get what it means by : Grant other members of your organization access to submission details; separate each address with a semicolon (;)

Comment: If you see the above note it mentions that every question marked with `*` is required.
Where as `Grant other members of your organization access to submission details; separate each address with a semicolon (;)` isn't marked so its not necessary to fill in.

Comment: But when I click continue, it takes me to the top to fill it in

Comment: Are you submitting the issue as a software developer?

Comment: yeah im submitting as a software developer, why?

Comment: it shouldnt be asking you this then